# mysql set names utf8 , "pokemon" and "pokémon" actually equal ？

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I test the mysql command line ,there is a problem confused me

```
set names utf8;

select STRCMP('pokemon','pokémon');
```

the result is zero

```
STRCMP('pokemon','pokémon')
0
```

i want it show -1 or 1 or something

i tried "set names latin1",It shows that they are not equal.

```
set names latin1;
select STRCMP('pokemon','pokémon');
```

the result is 1

```
STRCMP('pokemon','pokémon')
1
```

what's the problem?can i have the result like latin1 in utf8?

Comment: *Collation* is the concept you're looking for, not encoding. Collation rules implicitly follow from encoding settings, but you can set both separately.

Comment: For example, `select strcmp('pokemon' collate utf8_bin , 'pokémon');`

Comment: is there  other solutions?

Comment: no, not really - all string comparisons are done using some collation

Comment: Why use `STRCMP`?  Generally, one uses `WHERE` or `=` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 In all of these collations you will find that 'e' = 'ê'.
 utf8_czech_ci
 utf8_danish_ci
 utf8_esperanto_ci
 utf8_estonian_ci
 utf8_general_ci
 utf8_hungarian_ci
 utf8_icelandic_ci
 utf8_latvian_ci
 utf8_lithuanian_ci
 utf8_persian_ci
 utf8_polish_ci
 utf8_roman_ci
 utf8_romanian_ci
 utf8_sinhala_ci
 utf8_slovak_ci
 utf8_slovenian_ci
 utf8_spanish_ci
 utf8_spanish2_ci
 utf8_swedish_ci
 utf8_turkish_ci
 utf8_unicode_ci
```